# Core Data Attribute dependent on Relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to add an ordered array object to my CoreData setup, I know that you cannot do this as an NSSet is unordered, and I know that the simplest way to achieve this is to add an attribute to the entities within the set which can be used to order the set once you fetch it. However this is where I run into a problem with my setup, it's a little bit complicated:

I have entitities: `CricketPlayer` and `CricketTeam`... The user can create a `CricketTeam` object with an ordered array of `CricketPlayer's` which represents the batting lineup. When I next retrieve this list I want the lineup to be presented to the user in the same order in which they set it when creating a team... The only problem is within my app - the same goes in real life! - a player can play for more than one team so if I set an attribute on `CricketPlayer` say: `batterNumber` although this will enable me to re-create the batting lineup, if I then create another team with the same player in and bat him at a different position I will have ruined the batting lineup for the original team!

What I am therefore looking to do is create a 'pseudo-relationship' which is not a relationship to another CoreData entity but an attribute on an entity which depends on which entity it is being used within... so in my case I want an attribute on a `CricketPlayer` entity which represents that players batting number in a particular `CricketTeam` if that makes any sense at all!

Comment: Couldn't you use an ordered relationship?

Comment: Oooop apparently I could, that wasn't covered in the course I did haha! cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a few more entities.  I assume a player can play for a team more than once i.e. in more than 1 match, in a different order in the batting lineup.  So you need a match entity which links CricketTeams, and record the batting order of the teams for that specific match.

**Match**
HomeTeamID
AwayTeamID

**Team**
TeamID
TeamName

**Player**
PlayerID
PlayerName

**PlayerTeam**
PlayerID
TeamID

**MatchBattingOrder**
MatchID
PlayerID
TeamID
BattingOrder

This is very simplistic!  This is a data modelling issue

Comment: I already have a Match entity, so if I added into my setup a BattingOrder entity I could have a relationship from CricketMatch of HomeTeamLineUp and AwayTeamLineUp - which are both BattingOrder entities - , and store an NSOrderedSet of CricketPlayers in each of those lineups?

Comment: You don't need a separate HomeTeamLineUp and AwayTeaLineUp. The TeamID is stored in the MatchBattingOrder, so filter that table on a match, order by BattingOrder witin TeamID. You'll then have two lists, in the correct batting order, 1 for each team. Join it to the Team table (twice) to get the team names and to the player entity to get the player names. You need to think about where to store results!

Comment: In fact the MatchBattingOrder may be the place to store individual results for each game.  Each player is in there for each match, so you could have columns for their batting score, wickets taken, how out.  But you'd then need to think about how you cope with 2 innings matches, where to store whose wickets a bowler took and how etc.  It's a problem that will grow but sounds like a fun problem to solve.

Comment: Yeah it's proving pretty challenging haha! But I'm looking forward to trying to sort it all out! :)